# Jersey service returning 400 Bad Request with Must specify a non-null value for the 'to' index in a Range

Tags: java, jersey

I have a Jersey REST service that invokes several other REST services and combines their returns to form a new return. My unit tests pass, but in integration I get a 400 Bad Request and can not figure out who is returning that. Does Jersey parse input and return a 400?

```
@GET
@Path("/existing/{name}")
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
def namedFriction( @PathParam("name") String name, @Context HttpServletRequest request ) {
  Cookie ssoToken = HTTPUtils.getSSOCookie(request)
  def results = frictionBuilderService.checkCatalogForName(name, ssoToken)
  def requestUrl = HttpUtil.getBaseContextUrl( request )
  if ( results != null ) return frictionBuilderService.formatFriction(results, requestUrl)
  throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build() )
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

After 5 hours, I found the answer. I was looking in the wrong place. Turns out, Runtime exceptions are turned into 400 Bad Request by Jersey response handler. I was focused on other services when the issue was my own service throwing an IllegalArgumentException from a loop.

Place a try catch (Exception e) around your service impl and find the issue quickly. Jersey strips the stack trace when returning this error and it may not be from a remote service, might be your own code.

Placed here for posterity for any others so afflicted. I did not know where else to note this.

Comment: That's strange, if there is an error then it should be reported as 500 internal server error

Comment: Unbeknownst to me, another developer had added some exception providers that failed to log and returned 400 for a variety of exceptions.